# Maven dependency issues

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am working with Maven project and I am getting the below exception at the end-

> The following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.springsource.org:junit:jar:4.8.1,
>   com.springsource.com.mysql:jdbc:jar:5.1.6,
>   org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat:util:jar:7.0.0.2,
>   ucirrus:ucirrus:jar:1.1.0, com.springsource.org:jdom:jar:1.0.0,
>   com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.070125.1, org.apache:mina:jar:1.1.7,
>   com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.070125.1, org.apache:ahc:jar:1.1,
>   com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb1-impl:jar:2.1.070125.1: Could not find artifact
>   com.springsource.org:junit:jar:4.8.1 in releases

Below is my `pom.xml file`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.host.bulls.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>CassandraClient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CassandraClient</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repo</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>riptano</id>
            <name>riptano</name>
            <url>http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.scale7.org</id>
            <name>Scale7 Maven Repo</name>
            <url>https://github.com/s7/mvnrepo/raw/master</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.astyanax</groupId>
            <artifactId>astyanax</artifactId>
            <version>1.56.37</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scale7</groupId>
            <artifactId>scale7-pelops</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-1.1.x</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.host.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernelMerged</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me with this in solving this issues? Thanks

Comment: It should tell you the path of dependencies leading to the missing jar(s). That would be in the stdout listing. Can you find it?

Comment: By path what do you mean? I am only getting this exception at the end- `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project CassandraClient: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.host.bulls.cassandra:CassandraClient:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.springsource.org:junit:jar:4.8.1, com.springsource.com.mysql:jdbc:jar:5.1.6, org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat:util:jar:7.0.0.2, ucirrus:ucirrus:jar:1.1.0, com.springsource.org:jdom:jar:1.0.0, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.070125.1, org.apache:mina:jar:1.1.7,`

Comment: continuation from above,  `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.070125.1, org.apache:ahc:jar:1.1, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb1-impl:jar:2.1.070125.1: Could not find artifact com.springsource.org:junit:jar:4.8.1 in releases (http://nxraptor/content/repositories/releases) -> [Help 1]
[`

Comment: It says "Path to dependency:" like is shown here: http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/ about 3/4 of the way down. There will be several of these messages--one for each missing jar.

Comment: I am not getting those for some reasons. I have no idea why is it so. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output it seems maven can not find the com.springsource.org:junit:jar:4.8.1 dependency one of your other dependencies needs.

With a quick check it seems the dependency com.host.kernel:kernelMerged:1.13.1 could cause this problem because the other once did not have springsource as transitive dependency and I can not resolve the kernelMerged one with your config.

The com.springsource libraries are located in the springsource repo. So could you check the kernelMerged dependencies and his repo config and try to add the springsource repo to your pom.

See http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq

```
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```